# Is it possible to label bar charts?

Tags: qgis, diagram

I have added bar charts to my map and this works fine. But I have no idea how to add values to the bar chart. For example one bar shows the value of 2000 and another shows the value of 2100. Is it possible to show this values in the bar chart? I tried labeling but this is not what I want.

Any ideas? A Plugin or something else?

qgis 2.01 and 1.8

Thanks.

Comment: Well I really do not know what you want t do?? But using a text editor (like Microsoft word), can help you out.

Answer (score 1):

If nobody else has an idea, than here is my solution.

I've copied the layer. Now I've one layer or each bar. Than I used labeling to add the values to each bar. Not nice, but it is the only way I found.