# Values on top of each bar of a histogram in QGIS

Tags: qgis, labeling, chart, histogram, diagram

Is it possible to show the values on top of each bar of a histogram created with QGIS? (I am using QGIS 2.18)

[image]

I know this post [[Is it possible to label bar charts?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78868/is-it-possible-to-label-bar-charts]) addressed a similar question years ago, but it was unanswered, and maybe the program has evolved since, or someone has find a better solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm using QGIS 3.4, but this answer should also be possible in 2.18.

Unfortunately it doesn't look like there's a way to directly display the histogram values as part of the histogram. A workaround is to add field values as labels, and manually adjust the placement settings until they line up with the corresponding part of the diagram.

For example, I used multi-line labels with a horizontal histogram. It should be possible to this in any orientation, though.

[image]

As you can see the labels aren't perfectly aligned, but I set this up in just a few minutes. You can achieve better alignment with trial and error.

Use the `concat()` function to concatenate the fields into one long string separated by any one character. Then use that character as the line separator.

[image]

Label placement: offset from centroid. Use trial and error to figure out the best values for X,Y Offset (I used X: -3mm, Y: -7mm).

[image]

The diagram is right-oriented (layer diagram properties window > options tab)

[image]

with default-width bars (5mm) and with scaled size with a bar length of 10.

[image]

Diagram placement is "Around centroid".

Comment: Great explanation! As you say it is not the answer to the question but a very good workaroud. Thank you so much!!

Comment: This seems like a feature worth [requesting](https://issues.qgis.org). I did a quick search of the bug report/feature request site, and it doesn't look like anyone requested this feature yet.

Answer (score 1):

there is a similar way to do it with vertical chart orientation and numbers on top. 
[image]

place your labels with an "offset from centroid" and define the "Offset X,Y' via individual expression (the sum symbol at the right side of those two fields for x and y). in my case the expression was like this

`'7,' || to_string( "FIELD_01" *-7)`

'Offest X,Y' expects a string like this 'nn,mm' to move objects in x nn meters and in y mm meters.

"FIELD_01" ... the field with values from yellow columns. the expression at the right side multiplies the field-values by -7 to move them up according to max(FIELD_01)-values. this specific value -7 was identified by try and error ...

|| .... concatenates the x offset value and the epression for the y offset value.

units must be set to "Map Units" !!!

(grey bars are part of another experiment and should not be considered in this context !)